# Adding dynamically a DbSet<TEntity> in DbContext class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to add `DbSet<TEntity>` Property in `DbContext` class at runtime without passing through `OnModelCreating` ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to know?

Comment: You don't need a property, just call `db.Set<T>()`. But you do need the type defined in the model somehow.

Comment: What are you trying to do that would require you to do this?

Comment: I’m trying to add tables at runtime I succeeded to add class dynamically but I couldn’t update the DbContext class so that I can add my created class as DbSet<NewClass>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by dynamically creating a new type that inherits from `DbContext` and the use Reflection Emit to add the `DbSets` to this type.

It's a bit of a long solution to try and post into a response here, but here's a GitHub link to a working demo of how it can be done

[EF Core Dynamic Db Context](https://github.com/rschreiber/EFCoreDynamic)